# Transform data with Laravel helpers

Tags: php

I have an array with the following format:

```
[
  {
    "stat_month": "01-2019",
    "in_sum": 45443,
    "out_sum": 42838,
    "balance": 2605
  },
  {...}
]
```

But I want to transform this array, hopefully in one operation, to this:

```
[
  "labels" => ["01-2019", "02-2019", "03-2019"],
  "in_sum" => [45443, 60947, 56734],
  "out_sum" => [42838, 42151, 75486],
  "balance" => [2605, 18796, -18752]
]
```

Any ideas how to solve this in one operation with collection helper functions?

Comment: Sharing the JSON would be helpful

Comment: just do a foreach loop and merge the data. Have you tried something ? did you encounter an error ?

Comment: There is no way you can get from that shared input data (containng no occurences of `02-2019`) to the expected output data (where this magically pops up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at mapToGroups in Laravel Collections:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-maptogroups

or this solution:

```
$obj1 = new \stdClass;
$obj1->stat_month = "01-2019";
$obj1->in_sum = 45443;
$obj1->out_sum = 42838;
$obj1->balance = 2605;
$obj2 = new \stdClass;
$obj2->stat_month = "02-2019";
$obj2->in_sum = 55443;
$obj2->out_sum = 52838;
$obj2->balance = 3605;

$collection = collect([
    $obj1,$obj2
]);

$aResult = [
    'labels' => [],
    'in_sum' => [],
    'out_sum' => [],
    'balance' => []
];

$collection->each(function ($item, $key) use (&$aResult) {
    $aResult['labels'][] = $item->stat_month;
    $aResult['in_sum'][] = $item->in_sum;
    $aResult['out_sum'][] = $item->out_sum;
    $aResult['balance'][] = $item->balance;
});
```

Result:

```
array:4 [▼
  "labels" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "01-2019"
    1 => "02-2019"
  ]
  "in_sum" => array:2 [▼
    0 => 45443
    1 => 55443
  ]
  "out_sum" => array:2 [▼
    0 => 42838
    1 => 52838
  ]
  "balance" => array:2 [▼
    0 => 2605
    1 => 3605
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this is php like this:

```
<?php

$array = '[
  {
    "stat_month": "01-2019",
    "in_sum": 45443,
    "out_sum": 42838,
    "balance": 2605
  },
  {
    "stat_month": "01-2019",
    "in_sum": 45443,
    "out_sum": 42838,
    "balance": 2605
  },
  {
    "stat_month": "01-2019",
    "in_sum": 45443,
    "out_sum": 42838,
    "balance": 2605
  }
]';

$array = json_decode($array, true);

$arrayResult = [
                'stat_month' => array_column($array, 'stat_month'), 
                'in_sum' => array_column($array, 'in_sum'), 
                'out_sum' => array_column($array, 'out_sum'), 
                'balance' => array_column($array, 'balance')
];

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arrayResult);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simplified [array_map()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and receive desired output:

```
$i = 0;
$tmp = ['labels'=>[],'in_sum'=>[],'out_sum'=>[],'balance'=>[]];

array_map(function($obj) use (&$tmp, $i){
    foreach($tmp as &$val){ 
       $val[] = array_values(((array)$obj))[$i]; 
       $i++;
    }
},$ar);
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/EaE80)**

Or just simple `foreach loop`:

```
$tmp = ['labels'=>[],'in_sum'=>[],'out_sum'=>[],'balance'=>[]];

foreach($ar as $obj) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach($tmp as &$val){ 
       $val[] = array_values(((array)$obj))[$i]; 
       $i++;
    }
}
```

**[Demo2](https://3v4l.org/O2JXN)**

You can replace and re-write this code with Laravel [map()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-map) function. Try to use dynamic loops instead of predefined object's properties.